# Chef is running the wrong recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to set up Varnish in front of a Wordpress multi-site using Chef.  I am new to the system that was set up by others, and I'm a bit of a beginner in general.

I have created a new recipe and added it to the run list, but when I run chef-client, it executes a different recipe in place of the one I wrote.  Specifically, it runs the only recipe that my recipe includes.

Here is my recipe, which I copied almost verbatim from a pre-existing, working recipe that we use for a different site:

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: web_varnish_config
# Recipe:: wordpress
#

include_recipe 'web_varnish_config::default'

all_wordpress_backends = search(:node, "chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND roles:web_wordpress")
all_wordpress_backends.sort_by!{ |n| n[:fqdn] } # Sort the nodes to prevent config-order thrashing.

# Error state
if all_wordpress_backends.empty?
  Chef::Log.warn("At least one node with recipes:web_wordpress must exist for chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}. Skipping Varnish configuration.")
  return
end

template "/etc/varnish/default.vcl" do
  source "etc/varnish/wordpress.vcl.erb"
  mode "0644"
  variables(
    :all_wordpress_backends => all_wordpress_backends
  )
  notifies :restart, "service[varnish]", :delayed
end

# Use a share secret for our Varnish instances that is available to our Webservers
# so that Wordpress can clear the Varnish cache.
include_recipe 'chef-vault'
settings = chef_vault_item_for_environment("web_wordpress", "varnish")
if !settings.nil? and settings.key?('secret')
  file "/etc/varnish/secret" do
    content settings['secret']
    mode "0600"
    notifies :restart, "service[varnish]", :delayed
  end
end
```

When I run chef-client, it runs web_varnish_config::default instead of this recipe, web_varnish_config::wordpress.  This is what my chef-client output looks like (tried to copy all of it, but couldn't so here's the beginning and the end, what I think is most relevant):

```
Starting Chef Client, version 13.6.4
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["yum-epel::default", "serversetup-midd::cent7", "serversetup-midd::rootpassword", "midd_yum_cron::default", "fw-midd::default", "chef-client::config", "chef-client::default", "chef_client_updater::default", "centrify-midd::default", "centrify-midd::sshd", "midd_spacewalk::client", "commvault-midd::default", "serversetup-midd::webserver", "fw-midd::webserver", "centrify-midd::webserver", "chef-vault::default", "ssl-config-midd::miis", "ssl-config-midd::midd", "php-midd::default", "ssl-config-midd::wordpress", "web_php_config", "web_apache_config", "web_apache_config::ssl_context", "web_wordpress", "cookbook_versions::all", "ssl-config-midd::davisfellowsforpeace", "ssl-config-midd::davisprojectsforpeace", "ssl-config-midd::davisuwcscholars", "varnish-midd::default", "fw-midd::varnishserver", "web_varnish_config::backend", "web_varnish_config::wordpress"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - smbfs (0.5.0)
  - compat_resource (12.19.0)
  - web_php_config (1.1.0)
  - ohai (5.1.0)
  - midd_spacewalk (0.4.3)
  - windows (3.0.5)
  - yum (5.0.1)
  - firewalld (1.1.5)
  - cookbook_versions (1.0.0)
  - serversetup-midd (2.6.10)
  - commvault-midd (2.3.1)
  - cron (4.1.3)
  - php-midd (2.0.6)
  - ssl-config-midd (2.2.1)
  - chef-vault (3.0.0)
  - logrotate (2.2.0)
  - selinux (2.0.3)
  - ssh_authorized_keys (0.4.0)
  - chef_client_updater (2.0.3)
  - web_wordpress (2.0.10)
  - varnish-midd (2.0.3)
  - chef-client (8.1.6)
  - users (5.1.0)
  - yum-epel (2.1.2)
  - web_apache_config (2.0.10)
  - web_varnish_config (2.3.2)
  - sshd (1.3.1)
  - fw-midd (3.2.5)
  - midd_yum_cron (1.0.0)
  - web_sshkeys (1.0.2)
  - web_git_tracking_branch (1.1.0)
  - centrify-midd (3.1.1)
```

And at the end:

```
Recipe: web_varnish_config::backend
   * cookbook_file[/var/www/html/check.html] action create (up to date)
   * web_apache_config_vhost[vhost-7-wwwhealthcheck.conf] action create
   * template[/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-7-wwwhealthcheck.conf] action create (up to date)
 (up to date)
 # NOTE: Below is where I'm expecting web_varnish_config:wordpress
 Recipe: web_varnish_config::default
   * service[varnish] action enable (up to date)
   * template[/etc/varnish/varnish.params] action create (up to date)
   * service[varnishncsa] action enable (up to date)
   * service[varnishncsa] action start (up to date)
   * cookbook_file[/etc/systemd/system/varnishncsa.service] action create (up to date)
```

If I take out the include line, chef-client skips this entirely, without errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you think this recipe isn't running?

Comment: A couple things: When looking at the output from chef-client, it specifically says `Recipe: web_varnish_config::default` instead of `Recipe: web_varnish_config::wordpress`.  Another piece of evidence is that no changes I make in the wordpress recipe are ever reflected in Varnish's behavior (what led me down this rabbit hole in the first place)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output from chef-client.

Comment: Please include the _full_ output. You can see the parsed and expanded form of the run list at the top of the output.

Comment: So you can see the recipe on the run list there, it seems likely that your search isn't returning anything so the recipe doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is there some reason it wouldn't find it?  I figured it was at least seeing it, as when I comment out the include line at the top of the file, chef-client doesn't run either the default or wordpress recipe.

Comment: That's up to your environment. Try the search query via knife and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I had forgotten to update the name of a role in:

```
# I needed to change roles:web_wordpress to roles:web_wordpress_new
all_wordpress_backends = search(:node, "chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND roles:web_wordpress")
```

Which means my problem was extremely specific and probably not helpful to others, but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

Copying down from comments, the search in the recipe is likely returning no nodes and so the recipe is skipping itself as it was written to do.